# R RODBC sqlQuery and WHERE clause to search timestamps

Tags: r, timestamp, where-clause, rodbc

I cannot get the RODBC sqlQuery function to return queries with a WHERE clause that searches on a timestamp. The data type of the database is timestamp. I do not care about the time, I really just want the date (however, for future scalability knowing how to use the time might not be so bad). The following is a very simple example. I know these records exist.

```
sqlQuery(conn.prb, paste("SELECT * FROM x", 
"WHERE ENDDATE > 2014-12-22"), max=10)
```

The error I get is:

[1] "42818 -401 [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/AIX64] SQL0401N  The data types of the operands for the operation \">\" are not compatible or comparable.  SQLSTATE=42818\r\n"

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think you should enclose your date between ticks: `"select * from x where ENDDATE > '2014-12-22'"`

Comment: Just to be sure: which RDBMS are you using? SQL server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, ...?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, with DB2 ODBC drivers, dates need to be single-quoted within double-quoted SELECT statement.

Comment: It's standard in SQL for strings, dates, etc. to require single quotes. The easiest way to have an R string that includes single quotes is to use double quotes to mark the start and end of the string, but you could also escape the single quotes with a backslash.